# Customize error validation messages from Dropwizard

Tags: rest, dropwizard

I am making an application based on Dropwizard .I have the following representation that's called **Flight**, I used **annotations** to validate the form related to **Flight** representation.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity("Flight")
public class Flight {
    @Id
    String id;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone="CET")
    @NotNull
    private Date departureDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",  timezone="CET")
    @NotNull
    private Date arrivalDate;
    @NotNull
    private Airport arrivalAirport;
    // getters and setters methods ...
}
```

I use @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone="CET") to serialize this date with this format . I succeed to display error messages when I sent form with empty fields through the @NotNull, but when I type a invalid date format and empty fields in the same form I got only

```
{code: 400, message: "Unable to process JSON"}    
  code: 400    
  message: "Unable to process JSON"
```

*Is it possible to customize this error message of date validation and show the others validation messages at the same time?*

For example I got **"arrivalAirport: may not be null"** when I didn't enter only arrivalAirport value. 
 I want to receive for example:

```
**"departureDate: invalid date format"** 
**"arrivalAirport: may not be null"**
```

When I didn't enter an arrivalAirport value and an invalid format of departureDate value.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/validation.html#constraining-entities)? Basically you need a bunch of annotations at the POJOs: `@JsonProperty("name")` and at the endpoint level: `endpointMethod(@Valid Person person)`.